# How to restore FAT Partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, boot-camp, fat32

I have a MacBook Pro with 2 physical drives. Let's call them `System` and `Data`.

On `System`, I had 2 partitions, one with macOS and the other with Windows using BootCamp.

While trying to delete the Windows partition using BootCamp, I accidentally reformatted the exFAT partition on `Data` drive.

Once I realized what had happened, I used a recovery tool to recover files from the deleted partition on `Data`, and saved them in a folder on the macOS partition of the `System` drive.

In the recovered files, the recovery tool has recovered 2 files which I believe are the FAT tables of the deleted partition on the `Data` drive.

Is there a utility which I can use to restore the partition using the FAT tables recovered by the recovery utility?

Comment: Note that exFAT is structured quite differently from traditional FAT16/FAT32, and many recovery tools do not yet understand the new format.

Comment: I've been trying out TestDisk. It might actually be an FAT32 partition, according to TestDisk.

Comment: What's the benefit of restoring the drive to exactly what it was, over just reformatting? Did you not get all the data off it? Was it not backed up safely elsewhere?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I am hoping to recreate the lost contents of the drive. The contents that have been recovered do not have the names and folder hierarchy, etc. If I had a backup, I would not be seeking to do this, would I?